# creating and using standalone scalaz jar without sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, scalaz

I've downloaded scalaz snapshot from repository (version 6.0.4).
I want to create standalone jar file and put it into my scala lib directory to use scalaz without sbt.

I'have scala package from scala-lang.org, and stored in /opt/scala 
As far I did:

- go to untared scalaz directory
- run sbt from scalaz project
- compile scalaz project
- make a package (by package command)
- sbt make a jar  full/target/scala-2.9.1/scalaz-full_2.9.1-6.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar
- it also produce other jar: full/lib/sxr_2.9.0-0.2.7.jar
- I moved both jars to /opt/scala/lib

After this I try scala repl and I can't import scalaz. I tried to import `scalaz._`, `Scalaz._`, `org.scalaz._`, `scalaz-core._`  and don't work.
REPL code completition after typing `import scalaz` it suggest: `scalaz_2.9.1-6.0.4-SNAPSHOT`.
But `import scalaz_2.9.1-6.0.4-SNAPSHOT._` don't work

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can download [scalaz](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools/org/scalaz/scalaz-full_2.9.1/6.0.3/scalaz-full_2.9.1-6.0.3.jar) and extract the jar that contains `scalaz-core_2.9.1-6.0.3.jar`. Or [download scalaz-core directly](http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools/org/scalaz/scalaz-core_2.9.1/6.0.3/scalaz-core_2.9.1-6.0.3.jar).

then you can use : `scala -cp scalaz-core_2.9.1-6.0.3.jar` to launch the REPL finally `import scalaz._` as expected.

If you want to use the jar produced by sbt, you can find it in `core/target/scala-2.9.1/scalaz-core_2.9.1-6.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar` (you will also find source and javadoc packages in the same directory). Just put this file in your classpath (using `scala -cp` for example) and you will be able to `import scalaz._`

Comment: Not exactly - I want to make it from sbt.

Comment: @RobertZaremba I've modified my answer. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know the problem.

scalaz-full_2.9.1-6.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar is not a java jar class package, it's just a zip with scalaz project - so it contains not package - like directory tree (eg: directory names contains '.').

So to use it we need to unpack scalaz-full_2.9.1-6.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar, and copy desired jars (eg: scalaz-core_2.9.1-6.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar, scalaz-http_2.9.1-6.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar ...) to lib directory.